# In Internet Options, why does "Delete browsing history on exit" keep getting enabled automatically?

Tags: windows, browser, internet-explorer, history, microsoft-edge

*Super User has oodles of questions about how to avoid tracking and/or forget your browsing history. I'm looking to do the opposite. Hear me out.*

**Problem description**

I use Windows 10 64-bit. Infrequently I need to use Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge. I have IE 11.966.15063.0 and Edge 40.15063.674.0 installed. When I use these browsers, I would like to benefit from my browsing history in those browsers, such as visited site URLs, cookies, and cache. But I noticed recently that IE and Edge are rarely remembering my history. So I checked Internet Options and found this:

[image]

`Delete browsing history on exit` is checked. I never checked it.

If I uncheck it and click Apply or OK, all seems well for a little while. But at some point, my history disappears, and I find that `Delete browsing history on exit` is automatically checked again. Sometimes it's after a logout/login or reboot, but sometimes I'll be logged in for hours and then find that the box is checked again.

On the same computer, Chrome's browser history works fine.

**Questions**

1. Why would `Delete browsing history on exit` automatically get re-checked?
2. What can I do to stop this from happening?

**What I have tried**

- Uncheck the box and **OK** or **Apply** (as described above)
- **Internet Options > Advanced > Reset**
- Run `gpupdate /force` in a command prompt and then reboot (my computer is joined to a Windows domain; our IT staff says this isn't being caused by domain policy)

Comment: We are always glad to help, but please allow me to pass along one important piece of advice:  when your machine is on an Active Directory domain, it is absolutely *crucial* to include that information within your original post.  It really does make a huge difference regarding the pertinent recommendations.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely answer? Your computer is joined to a Windows domain.

Delete ... on exit is a setting that can be applied from the domain, and if it continually re-enables itself on your computer, then that is the most likely explanation.

Speak with the IT staff who manage the domain to confirm this.

*You may wonder why, if this is set at the domain level, why you can disable it. This is likely because the Delete... setting is applied, but "Prevent people from changing this setting" is not applied.*

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that the IT staff suggested the `gpupdate` and don't know why this is happening. So I doubt it's in the domain policy.

Comment: Please add that information to your post. That said, your IT staff bear primary responsibility for diagnosing and resolving this issue. It may be another system they are using (SCCM, Antivirus software) which applies this setting.

Comment: I would tend to agree with this answer.  I realize that your IT staff says that it is not a domain GPO, but based upon my 20-plus years managing Windows networks I think there is a high degree of probability that *some* type domain configuration is causing this.  In other words, is this the default behavior within Internet Explorer on a Windows 10 x64 machine that **isn't** on a domain?  No, so it's a rather safe assumption that something within that domain (GPO, SCCM, Windows Updates, scripts, etc.) is causing it.

Comment: It sounds pretty unanimous to me. I will once again nag the IT staff and I'll update you here with news (and hopefully votes). Thanks all.

Comment: @GaryS. it has been a while.  Have you made any progress?

Comment: @Run5k thanks for the follow-up. No, no progress. My IT staff promises that the domain policy is not checking that box. But the consensus here indicates that the domain policy is doing it. As someone who is not a domain administrator (obviously!), and as someone who only needs to use IE for one and only one purpose, I have given up. Many thanks to all who offered help.